# Distribution of the logical OR of a binary random variable with a uniform distribution?

Tags: logic, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binary

Suppose X and Y are binary random variables that have a uniform random distribution. Suppose Z is the logical OR of X and Y.

What is the distribution P(ZX)?

I know that A has a 1/2 chance each of taking on A=0 or A=1 since it has a uniform distribution, but the logical or Z is throwing me off since it includes Y which is not mentioned in problem question.

Comment: The logical OR operator returns the value $1$ if either or both operands is $1$ and returns $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: Yes, X and Y are assumed independent.